# No other transition works except Fade, nivoSlider

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, nivo-slider

There are no effects working on the nivoSlider except fade. Check out their official site:

http://demo.dev7studios.com/nivo-slider/demo-3/

It says: Nivo Slider with Dark Theme & Random Settings

But, the only effect seen is Fade.

Is anyone aware of this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there may be a confusion on this page.

it says: "Nivo Slider with Dark Theme & Random Settings", but looking at the source code, you can see that the effect is set to "fade". I think by "random settings" they just mean random animation timing, slices, etc; not the actual effect of the transitions.

You can still use 'random' and it should preform the way it should:

```
$('CONTAINER').nivoSlider({
    effect: 'random'
});
```